# Using STL Decomposition Terms in a GAM Model for Time-Series Analysis of Disease Mortality and Air Pollution

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I'm a medical researcher exploring the association between disease mortality and air pollution using time-series analysis. I'm considering using STL decomposition terms (trend, seasonal, and residual components) in my Generalized Additive Model (GAM) instead of standard calendar time and day-of-week terms. The proposed R code structure is:

```
gam_model <- gam(target_variable ~ s(trend_component, bs="cr") + 
                 s(seasonal_component, bs="cr") +
                 s(residual_component, bs="cr") +
                 other_predictors,
                 data = data)
```

As I'm not a statistician, I'm unsure about the validity of this approach. Any insights or opinions would be greatly appreciated.

```
gam_model <- gam(target_variable ~ s(trend_component, bs="cr") + 
                 s(seasonal_component, bs="cr") +
                 s(residual_component, bs="cr") +
                 other_predictors,
                 data = data)
```

Comment: Why do you use `cr` in s()? Is it because the shape of your model?